# 8Puzzle game with A* : What structure for the open set?

Tags: python, algorithm, complexity-theory, a-star, sliding-tile-puzzle

I'm developing a 8 Puzzle game solver in python lately and I need a bit of help
So far I finished coding the A* algorithm using Manhattan distance as a heuristic function.

The solver runs and find ~60% of the solutions in less than 2 seconds
However, for the other ~40%, my solver can take up to 20-30 minutes, like it was running without heuristic.

I started troubleshooting, and it seems that the openset I use is causing some problems :

- My open set is an array
- Each iteration, I loop through the openset to find the lowest f(n) (complexity : O(n) )

I have the feeling that O(n) is way too much to run a decent A* algorithm with such memory used so I wanted to know how should I manage to make the openset less "time eater"

Thank you for your help ! Have a good day

EDIT: FIXED

I solved my problem which was in fact a double problem.

I tried to use a dictionary instead of an array, in which I stored the nodes by their f(n) value and that allowed me to run the solver and the ~181000 possibilities of the game in a few seconds

The second problem (I didn't know about it because of the first), is that I didn't know about the solvability of a puzzle game and as I randomised the initial node, 50% of the puzzles couldn't be solved. That's why it took so long with the openset as the array.

Comment: Do you have a specific technical problem? If you consider the performance of the program itself to be the issue, can you share your code? You might have better luck on https://cs.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Hi @AlexanderCécile ! Thanks for your answer, I fixed my problem and edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The open set should be a **priority queue**. Typically these are implemented using a **binary heap**, though other implementations exist.

Neither an array-list nor a dictionary would be efficient.

---

The closed set should be an efficient **set**, so usually a **hash table** or **binary search tree**, depending on what your language's standard library defaults to.

A dictionary (aka "map") would technically work, but it's conceptually the wrong data-structure because you're not mapping to anything. An array-list would not be efficient.